# Pydev import standard Python module

Tags: pydev

As you can see from the screenshot, I am trying to import a standard Python module in the Pydev editor and it is claiming that 'Queue' has the problem 'Undefined variable from import: Queue'. As you can see in the screenshot, the code works in the Pydev console, and also (not shown) in the Python Idle console and editor. Can anyone explain why Pydev is unable to import this module in the Pydev editor where other environments, including the Pydev console have no problems.

[image: Screenshot showing situation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I need to add 'multiprocessing' to the list of forced builtins in the Pydev configuration which resolved my problem.